# How to validate decimal places for dynamic data?

Tags: javascript

I have generated following type of textarea fields using loop:

```
<textarea id="txta_<?=$sno?>" value="<?php echo $sno; ?>"
onkeyup="validateDecimal(<?php echo $sno;?>,<?php echo $decimal_value; ?>)"
onkeypress="return isNumberKey(<?php echo $sno;?>,event)"
name="txta_<?=$sno?>"><?=$row->parameter_result?></textarea>
```

For more simplification, text field would be somthing like this:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="adminForm" >
<textarea id="txta_1" value="<?php echo $sno; ?>" onkeyup="validateDecimal(1,3)" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(<?php echo $sno;?>,event)" name="txta_2" style="width: 185px; height: 22px;"><?=$row->parameter_result?></textarea>
<br />
<textarea id="txta_2" value="<?php echo $sno; ?>" onkeyup="validateDecimal(2,2)" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(<?php echo $sno;?>,event)" name="txta_2" style="width: 185px; height: 22px;"><?=$row->parameter_result?></textarea>
<br />
<textarea id="txta_3" value="<?php echo $sno; ?>" onkeyup="validateDecimal(3,1)" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(<?php echo $sno;?>,event)" name="txta_3" style="width: 185px; height: 22px;"><?=$row->parameter_result?></textarea>
</form>
```

I need to allow user to enter digits upto the allowed decimal places. The decimal places comes from the database.
So, allowed decimal places for txta_1 might be different from txta_2.
That is, txta_1 can have maximum 3 decimal places and txta_2 can have maximum 2 decimal places or might be other depending upon value from the database.

I have tried regex for it but could not reach the solution. How can this be done?

Comment: The gist of the problem is JavaScript related, not PHP; hence the retag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript would be much easier for this question. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateDecimal(sidd,decimalvalue)    {
    var sid = sidd;
    var decimal = decimalvalue;
    var txtdata = document.getElementById('txta_'+sid).value;   
    var s = txtdata.split('.');

      if (s[1].length > decimal) {
        alert( "Result should be upto " + decimal +" decimal number." );
         var textdata = parseFloat(txtdata).toFixed(decimal);
         document.getElementById('txta_'+sid).value = textdata;
      }
}
</script>
```

See Demo at [Codepad>>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/e123sn)